# Stripping down to just User-Folder from %USERPROFILE% - BATCH

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a scenario where users personal folders are being created in the format of user.domain. Eg: `C:\Users\John.Doe.CORP\*`. The issue is I have scripts which utilize `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\` which now translates to `C:\Users\John.Doe\*` and breaks the script.

I would like to do something like follows but need help w/ doing it in batch:

```
set USERDIR=echo %USERPROFILE% | sed -i -e 's|C:\users\||g' 
echo %USERDIR%
John.Doe.Corp
```

Eg strip the `C:\Users\` from the `%USERPROFILE%` so that even if `%USERNAME%` doesn't match `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\` I can use `C:\Users\%USERDIR%\`

Comment: what's the problem with using `%USERPROFILE%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding your question, but I think what you want is create a variable that just has the username followed by a dot, followed by the domain.

This could be as simple as:

```
set User=%USERNAME%.%USERDOMAIN%
```

If you really want to strip this from the users's path, and you can be assured it is always in c:\Users, then the following can be used:

```
set user=%USERPROFILE:C:\Users\=%
```

The above basically does a search and replace on %USERPROFILE% to remove `C:\Users\`from the string and store it in variable `%User%`.

On my end, there is no trailing \, so I did not have to remove it.

But if all you want to do is use C:\Users\Username.Domain, which is already stored in `%USERPROFILE%`, just use that path, no need to change it.

EDIT: your comment on this answer finally tells us the informatation that was lacking, which is: what is the end result?

Because of that, I'm going to suggest a different solution.

You mention that you have the path C:_users_username_domain_appdata, and given that there are only 3 folders inside appdata, and usually roaming is the one you want, %appdata% would be the path you would want to use. You can get that path formatted correctly by using the following set command:

```
set excellappdata=%appdata:\=_%
```

if you don't want the roaming part at the end, also execute the following:

```
set excellappdata=%excellappdata:_roaming=%
```

For more information about replacing a text with another text in the string, please refer to: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: That is perfect, the reason is because I have a script which uses %USERNAME% to replace the username in a path of `Excel.OfficeUI` which uses paths in the form of `C:_Users_Username_AppData` so I just replace `Username` with `%USERNAME%` but that no longer worked correctly, this will be a future proof fix for this issue as I know the path will be correct.

Comment: Can you eplain the code a  bit? I'm so used to bash lol, what tools did you use? No `sed/awk`!? I'm lost, looks like you just use magic `:`

Comment: This is native functionality of the commandline. Also, if you want to refer to the APPData folder, you may want to use the following: %APPDATA% for appdata\roaming and %LOCALAPPDATA% for appdata\local. These will always work, no matter where a policy moves the appdata as they are set during login, and they also work for computers that are not domain joined.

Comment: I know all the windows variables but I can't use full paths or variables as explained above due to irregular file path formats I need to just replace `USERNAME` with `USERPROFILE` folder. I appreciate the answer, I have updated script and resolve issue, but I didn't learn much about windows commandline functionality. I figured it was "native", but still don't understand the syntax of the command. Is `:` a separator and `=%` means set variable to everything after separators>?

Comment: Answer updated. :)